# Delete gnome desktop and now update "failed to fetch"

Tags: unity, gnome, updates

After update on 14.10 I had some trouble with unity not working( I made mistake and install `gnome-desktop` than I tried to delete `gnome` and reinstall `unity`.

But I made mistake again and executed:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And this really deleted `gnome` with drivers and other files ( about 300 mb.  I tried to executed:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But now I have `"failed to fetch"`  for all repositories ( and ping Google.com returned `"unknown host"`  can I fix it or I need to reinstall linux os?

Comment: common symptoms of dns issue.. "failed to fetch" for all reposetories( and ping Google.com returned "unknown host"

Comment: check cat /etc/resolv.conf to check dns and ifconfig to verify your ipsettings and route command to check default gateway.. If they are not in order you can set them, manually

Answer (score 0):

1. Start at boot into the GRUB menu
2. Select <kbd>Recovery Mode</kbd> for your latest kernel
3. Activate the network
4. Open the root shell

Now you have a network and can do what you need.

Comment: @user3927708 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)